# Error during installation of Ubuntu LTS 14.04.3

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, usb

My main OS is Windows 10 Home Edition (64-bit). I have an 8 GB USB 2.0 flash drive that I used to boot off of using the Universal USB Installer software from pendrivelinux.com. The software takes the linux ISO and automatically formats the USB for booting so all I have to do is reboot and spam F11 to choose to boot off of the USB.

This is where my problem occurs. After booting off of the USB, code (stuff that I don't understand) goes scrawling down the screen. After this, the Ubuntu logo appears and then after a few seconds the screen goes black and an error message appears. [After booting from the USB the Ubuntu logo appears and then this screen comes up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IStw.jpg)

My laptop currently has SAMSUNG 850 EVO M.2 SATA 6Gb/s SSD (120GB x 2) in RAID 0 and a 1 TB 7200RPM SATA300 Hard Drive. There is still plenty of space left in both of these for the Linux OS so I'm not sure what the problem could be.

I hope I gave enough information, but if I left anything out let me know!

Comment: When the options to either "Install Ubuntu" or "Try Ubuntu" come up, select the try option, but don't hit Enter yet. Instead, press `e`. Use your arrow keys to navigate the cursor to the end of the line that starts with `linux` and add `nouveau.modeset=0`. Press `f10`. If that doesn't work, recreate the install media using [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie)

Comment: Thanks Zacharee1, I'm not sure what the whole 'nouveau.modeset=0' did but it worked the second time around. I tried it with my initial media and that didn't work. Afterwards I switched to Rufus and had the same problem. After typing it with the media created with Rufus I was able to successfully boot up.

Comment: Nice! Hopefully, you shouldn't have to put that same thing in when you actually boot Ubuntu (you most likely won't). Tell me how it goes after the installation so I can post a full answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, after trying to install linux fully from after this short fix, I receive another error. During the installation process, when prompted to select my location I receive an error message that is just "??? ???" in a little popup window. This installation is quite the bother...

Comment: Strange. Remake the media and try again.

Answer (score 0):

for sure that is not a problem of available space. Seems that for some reason your installation image is not correct. The message on the bottom says, that installer cannot find /dev/sdc device containing installation image.

You mentioned about 2 SDDs in RAID mode. My guess is following: hardware RAID under windows is recognized as single drive (which is normal). So this is virtually mapped to /dev/sda. Under linux - those devices can be seen separately. So you'll get /dev/sda and /dev/sdb. Then, your HDD will be /dev/sdc (instead of expected USB drive). But this is only my guess.

Now, to try solve your problem - first I'd change Universal USB Installer to something else. Maybe you're more lucky then. Kubuntu (which is the same OS family) is suggesting UNetbootin (https://unetbootin.github.io/) - you may give it a try before digging into details of your hardware setup - maybe it will just work.

Please drop some info if you try this.

Good luck.

Comment: Unetbootin is just as bad as UUI on Windows.

Comment: Maybe - but usually the question is "boots or not boots". Afterwards I have never had a problem with installation when the boot itself was OK.

Comment: What about installing newer Ubuntu? Maybe 14.04 LTS is having some particular problem with that machine (rare but still possible...)

Comment: No, it's also an issue with the Nouveau graphics driver. I have the problem on 15.10, so a newer kernel is unlikely to help.